# How to disable ActiveModel::Serializers for a specific controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers, rails-api

We're using [active_model_serializers - 0.8.1](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/v0.8.1) in a Rails application.

The app has some API specific controllers inheriting from ActionController::Metal in a way similar to [rails-api](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api)'s [ActionController::API](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api/blob/master/lib/rails-api/action_controller/api.rb).

Well we want to use ActiveModel::Serializers only for the API controllers mentioned above.
Is that possible, how?

Note:
As mentioned in the [documentation](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/v0.8.1#getting-the-old-version) use of a serializer can explicitly be avoided by replacing

`render :json`

with:

`render :json => @your_object.to_json`

We are seeking a more elegant solution than the one above.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you give a code example that illustrates what you're aiming for?  I think that would help greatly clarify your question.

Comment: @Davidann we wished to be able to whitelist controllers on which active_model_serializers act via an option.

Answer (score 6):

You can also do:

```
respond_with @your_object, serializer: nil
```

Comment: It seems like the syntax for this has changed:
https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/2221

Answer (score 6):

For people who encounter this question in the future, adding `adapter: nil` to the `render: json...` will work (instead of `serializer: nil`)

Answer (score 5):

You can override the `default_serializer_options` method on a controller to disable serializers for all actions in that controller.

```
def default_serializer_options
  {
    serializer: nil
  }
end
```

We're currently generating our JSON in other ways, but I wanted to investigate `ActiveModel::Serializers` for a particular resource. This is when I discovered that adding the gem means that *all* controllers will try to use serializers. Not just the one in which I wanted to test the approach.

Using the serializers by default is great going forward, but we'll need some time to transition existing controllers to this approach. I updated those other existing controllers to not use the serializers (using the above method), so I can add the serializers on a controller-by-controller basis going forward.

Answer (score 2):

I was having an issue that also required disabling serialization, so I created [this pull request](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/pull/458) that adds the ability to disable serialization in a specific controller by calling `disable_serialization` in a controller.

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is kind of old and the solutions offered here are outdated just wanted to share my solution to have [ActiveModel::Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) and [FastJsonApi](https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi) by Netflix

The solution I made works for `ActiveModel::Serializers` 0.10.

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class ApplicationController < ActionController::API

  private

  def _render_with_renderer_json(json, options)
    json = json.to_json(options) unless json.kind_of?(String)
    self.content_type ||= Mime[:json]
    json
  end
end
```

I just restored the original method `_render_with_renderer_json` of Ruby on Rails 5.x (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb#L156-L169).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's an elegant solution.  It looks like you'd have to monkeypatch ActionController::Serialization - https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/5a92e00b51927c9c0e7c90f92c825aff09314bfd/lib/action_controller/serialization.rb.

The minimal change would probably by overriding the `build_json_serializer` method and returning nil in the controllers where you don't want to use ActiveModelSerializers.  If `build_json_serializer` in a controller always returns nil, then the behavior should default to non-AMS serialization

Unfortunately this class doesn't seem well structured for modification (private methods, etc.) so you may want to submit a pull request to make your task easier.  Either keeping an alias to the 'original' `_render_option_json` method before AMS inclusion, making the `build_json_serializer` protected rather than private, or adding a config option to disable AMS on a per-controller basis would all be reasonable modifications.

Answer (score 1):

Just a heads up that @dbj's answer, while correct, won't work in Rails4 due to the fact that respond_with was moved.

> NoMethodError: The `respond_with` feature has been extracted to the `responders` gem. Add it to your Gemfile to continue using this feature:
>     gem 'responders', '~> 2.0'
>   Consult the Rails upgrade guide for details.

The simple fix, found by guessing really, was to just do:

`render json: @you_object, serializer: nil`